# Spitzenkandidaten and nominating Commissioners

Tags: european-union

If I understand correctly, in the Spitzenkandidat process each EU party nominates a candidate for Commission presidency.

Do those nominees have proposed Commission appointees? Or does the installed President have to work with the Commissioners they are given via the process of member states’ nominations?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

They have to work with the commissioners they are given, that hasn't changed. The president doesn't get to build a cabinet of more-or-less like-minded politicians from the winning party or coalition as might happen in a parliamentary democracy, s/he has to accommodate the various national governments. The *Spitzenkandidaten* process was created to make the election feel more democratic and to ensure that the people see that their votes have a direct impact of some sort but it is not part of the treaties and does not sit well with the structure of EU institutions.

Of course, there can be discussions before the nominations, including *between the member states* and they will be mindful of the signals sent by the parliament. And it's also true that some positions are more important than others. It is necessary to have 28 commissioners because there are 28 member states but not all of them have as much power as, say, the commissioner for competition. So you can always “neutralize” a poor nominee by giving them a less important role.

There is however a major exception to this: The country where the president comes from. They don't get to nominate an extra commissioner, potentially losing the opportunity to place a member of the ruling party in the commission and having to live with the choice of an opposition party's allies in other countries (imagine Merkel effectively nominating the French commissioner when Hollande was president). Here again, the (European) parties are reducing the member state's role and that's why the process has been disputed since the beginning.